# Javascript Email validation that allows a null value

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, email, null

I have this on submit function that checks for the email field to have a properly formatted address. Works fine. However, I want the field to allow a null value as this particular input is optional and not required. I know this should be simple, Im missing the obvious. Someone point me in the right direction...

EDIT: Providing the entire form validation this time. As every time I just replace the email portion its breaking other pieces....

```
function validateSMSForm()
{
if (SMSForm.PID_Form.value.length < 4)
{
alert("Please enter a valid Partner ID");
return false;
}
if (SMSForm.area.value.length < 3)
{
alert("Please enter a valid 10-digit cell phone number");
return false;
}
if (SMSForm.prefix.value.length < 3)
{
alert("Please enter a valid 10-digit cell phone number");
return false;
}
if (SMSForm.line.value.length < 4)
{
alert("Please enter a valid 10-digit cell phone number");
return false;
}

<!-- EMAIL VALIDATION HERE
  if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(form.emailaddress.value))  
    {  
    return (true)  
    }  
    alert("Please enter a valid email address")  
    return (false) 

-->
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

Assuming

`<form onsubmit="return validateSMSForm(this)">`

JavaScript:

```
function isEmail(str) {
  return !str || /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,})+$/.test(str);
}

function validateSMSForm(SMSForm) {
  if (SMSForm.PID_Form.value.length < 4) {
    alert("Please enter a valid Partner ID");
    return false;
  }

  if (SMSForm.area.value.length < 3 ||
      SMSForm.prefix.value.length < 3 || 
      SMSForm.line.value.length < 4) {
    alert("Please enter a valid 10-digit cell phone number");
    return false;
  } 

  if (!isEmail(SMSForm.emailaddress.value)) {
    alert("Please enter a valid email address")  
    return false; // 
  }

  return true; // allow submission
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to negate email first :) Made the same mistake at first.

Comment: this wont work for me. is it because i have it wrapped in a greater set of functions for on submit validation?

Comment: Updated to use your code and to allow an address like something@something.info

Comment: perfection. TY sir. Works brilliantly. Also ty for the clean up, I knew I could consolidate some of that, but was being super lazy about it.

Answer (score 2):

Add a check for empty/null string first:

```
if ((!form.emailaddress.value) || (/^\w+([.-]?\w+)@\w+([.-]?\w+)(.\w{2,3})+$/.test(form.emailaddress.value))) {
    //handle valid e-mail
} else {
    //handle invalid e-mail
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var email = form.emailaddress.value;
if (!email){ return true } // this what your looking for?
if (/^\w+([.-]?\w+)@\w+([.-]?\w+)(.\w{2,3})+$/.test(email))
{
    return (true)
}
alert("Please enter a valid email address")
return (false)
```

Comment: the above works to allow a null value, but then ignores the secondary format validation.